# How to delete audio file created using built in sound recorder

Tags: android, android-file

I am newbie to this forum and android as well. Sorry for my weak English.

I am programming for Android 1.5. In my application, I want to record an audio using built-in sound recorder. For this, I am starting a sound recorder using action -

```
"MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION"
```

for an Intent. In `onActivityResult()`, I had copied the newly created audio file to my custom folder e.g. `/sdcard/myRecordings/sound_1.3gpp`.

Now I want to delete the original file created by sound recorder.

In DDMS view, I had seen that files were created in a folder -

```
"/sdcard/recordingXXXX.3gpp"
```

The file name contains XXXX; these are digits that will change every time whenever I am recording audio using sound recorder. I have searched the Internet, but have never found a helpful solution for - "how can I delete this file?" or "how can I get the location of these files programmatically?" (as I am viewing them in DDMS view)

Someone suggested to use `ContentResolver` to delete file by specifying the Uri returned by sound recorder activity. I had done this using -

```
ContentResolver oContentResolver = getContentResolver();
oContentResolver.delete(oUri, null, null);
```

But only the Uri entry is deleted and the file remains in the folder mentioned above. One suggestion was to start media scanner activity. I had done this using -

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(
      Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, 
      Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
```

I have added the appropriate intent filter in manifest file, but this stops the emulator when I start my application.

Can anyone give some insight on this? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Hi all, Can anyone guide me to solve this problem? Please.